Why am I unable to access my object in the console?
Given a class definition and creating an object of the class, when trying to access the object in console, I get an error "dodger_hat is not defined".
class Hat {
constructor(
    size,
    color,
    team,
    snapback,
){
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.team = team;
    this.snapback = snapback;
}
changeColor(newColor){
    this.color = newColor;
    console.log("The color has been changed to ", newColor);
}
changeTeam(newTeam){
    this.team = newTeam;
    console.log("The team has been changed to ", newTeam);
}
};

const dodger_hat = new Hat(8,"blue", "dodgers", false);

What I try
In the console

dodger_hat

what I expect to output

dodger_hat{size: 8, color: "blue", team : "dodgers", snapback : false};


I copied your code and runned in the console, worked just fine.... https://ibb.co/JvVRdw2

is that code in a <script type="module">

@JaromandaX Yes, I have <script type="module"> implemented in my .html file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts

@Jaromanda X — it does not matter if it is a Web application script, or node.js, a module or not, or anything else. No matter whatsoever. I answered the question.

@Paulo Fernando — Of course. The only problem is awkward debugging. I answered the question, it should resolve this not quite a real issue at once.

@PauloFernando - are you sure about that, sparky? Give it a go, in a <script type="module"> - perhaps then you'll understand why I asked my question

Everything works perfectly with this code. The debug console shows dodger_hat correctly:
Hat {size: 8, color: 'blue', team: 'dodgers', snapback: false}

The only possible problem is your observation. Perhaps you've inspected dodger_hat at the moment of execution when it was not yet constructed, something like that.
Imagine the case when you put a breakpoint at the last line on your code, const dodger_hat = //.... At this point, dodger_hat is not yet defined. The debug console on dodger_hat will show
undefined

A related debugging problem is that the line calling the constructor is the very last line of your code. If you use the breakpoint on this line, you will need to make one more step, but it will terminate the entire process. One simple workaround could be adding another line, anything executable:
  const dodger_hat = new Hat(8,"blue", "dodgers", false);
  console.log("You can set a breakpoint here");

Now, when your execution under the debugger reaches this last line without executing it, you can inspect dodger_hat at this point.
The issue does not exist.

The only possible problem is your observation. - no, the issue is that variables defined in modules are not global, sparky - OP confirmed that the script is in a <script type="module"> - and therefore, variables defined in such scripts are not global - at least you tried

@Jaromanda X — “the issue is that variables defined in modules are not global.” I don't think so. More importantly, this is not part of the question. The code is perfectly clear and self-contained, it creates a fully-defined object which is correctly explained. That's it. What do you mean “you tried”? This is exactly what it is. Everything else is the fantasy, unless OP reveals something else.

yeah, OK, carry on
